# In Javascript, what does return with semi-colon 'return;' mean

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In the handleSumit function below, what does it mean to return with just the semi-colon. Note: I know return is used to terminate a function in javascript and semi-colon terminates a statement.

```
this.state = { items: [], text: '' };

handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (!this.state.text.length) {
      return;
    }
}
```

Comment: `return undefined;`. Try it in your browser console (F1) to see it in action `(() => { return; })()`.

Comment: "_I know return is used to terminate a function in javascript and semi-colon terminates a statement._". You basically answered your own question. There isn't much more to it.

Comment: BTW, the semicolon is particularly unnecessary after an empty `return` because ASI (automatic semicolon insertion, by the parser) is mandatory in that case — regardless of what's on the next line — as long as `return` is the last token on its line.

Comment: I wanted clarification on the undefined part. I didn't know. But in the handleSubmit function if this.state.text.length is truthy what happens?

Comment: In this specific case? absolutely nothing. I'd assume there used to be more to this function or that it was copied from somewhere else that had more.

Comment: @KevinB this is a function from the official react docs and there is nothing more to it. I understand the use of the return; in this function now

Comment: There is literally no use for this return in this function as it is presented in your question. it does nothing that wouldn't also occur if the if statement was simply omitted (along with the return)

Comment: @KevinB alright. noted with thanks

Answer (score 4):

The `return;` statement returns `undefined` to the caller of the function.

From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return

```
return [[expression]];
```

> **expression**
>
> The expression whose value is to be returned. If omitted, undefined is
>   returned instead.

Comment: I'm not sure why this answer is downvoted, it provides a snippet and a resource on what `return;` actually does instead of answering with a common usage.

Answer (score 0):

If you're in a function and a certain condition is met, you might want to exit the function or terminate it. This is what return; does